# Unable to install VMWare Workstation v8

Tags: software-installation, vmware-workstation

Installing VMware 8.0.2 64bit

Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64bit BETA

My Kernel version is: 3.2.0-20-generic

```
pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$ sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2- 591240.x86_64.bundle
```

Installs ok

When I launch I am asked to install modules which are compiled and loaded into the running kernel.

A window opens

> VMware Kernel Module Updater
>
> This fails on Virtual Network Device

**[ERROR LOG](http://paste.ubuntu.com/903127/).**

**UPDATE:**

[PATCH](http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/).

When I try to add patch, following error:

```
 pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$ sudo sh patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
 [sudo] password for pst007x: 
 patch-modules_3.2.0.sh: 27: [: workstation8.0.2: unexpected operator
 patch-modules_3.2.0.sh: 28: [: workstation8.0.2: unexpected operator
 Sorry, this script is only for VMWare WorkStation 8.0.2 or VMWare Player 4.0.2. 
 Exiting
 pst007x@pst007x-Aspire-5741:~$
```

I have fully un-installed, and re-installed. I am installing the correct version. Probably a problem with the patch.
VMware installs perfectly on Ubuntu 11.10

This is how I [uninstalled](http://paste.ubuntu.com/903139/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put together this from various responses:

#### Move to Home folder

1. VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.bundle
2. PATCH: patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
3. PATCH: vmware3.2.0.patch

> Patch download link (xtact contents to Home folder):
>
> http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/2012/01/26/vmware-workstation-8-0-2-player-4-0-2-fix-for-linux-kernel-3-2-and-3-3/

#### Install VMware

```
sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64.bundle
```

#### Install Patch

```
sudo ./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```

NB: Make sure patch has an executable permission

Answer (score 7):

To disable the version check

- open the script *.sh in an editor (gedit)
- scroll down to line 27
- add "#" at the beginning of line 27,28,29
- save the script
- try to run the script again

or go to

- `cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source`
- `sudo tar xvf vmnet.tar`
- This will decompress files in `vmnet-only` folder
- Suppose you have the patch file at `~/Downloads/vmware802fixlinux320/vmware3.2.0.patch`
- `sudo patch -p1 <~/Downloads/vmware802fixlinux320/vmware3.2.0.patch`
- `sudo mv vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.bak`
- `sudo tar cvf vmnet.tar vmnet-only/`

Re-run the VMware Workstation or Player. In case, you might need to install

- `sudo apt-get install patch`

Comment: or change the version at line 7/8, for example `vmreqver=8.0.4` to apply the patch to vmware workstation 8.0.4

Answer (score 2):

There is known issues in trying to get VMWare workstation to install and/or work on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Best bet is to wait for the full release next month, or revert back to Ubuntu 11.10. I know this sounds unproductive, but I had the same issues, and I decided to revert back to Ubuntu 11.10 for the time being.

Comment: Found a solution (above) thanks. You are right there are bugs, but there are always bugs whether pre-release or 'finished' product. This beta release has resolved NVidia performance issues I was having, otherwise I would stick to an earlier version. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Same situation here: Correct version of VMPlayer and patch is still claiming that it is not the correct version.

My solution: I have skipped the versioncheck in patch-modules_3.2.0.sh by uncommenting the following lines with a "#". After uncommenting the lines the patch works and my player ist now working.

```
[ -z "$vmver" ] && error "VMWare is not installed (properly) on this PC"

[ "$vmver" == "workstation$vmreqver" ] && product="VMWare WorkStation"

[ "$vmver" == "player$plreqver" ] && product="VMWare Player"

[ -z "$product" ] && error "Sorry, this script is only for VMWare WorkStation $vmreqver or VMWare Player $plreqver"
```

Be careful with my answer. After rebooting my system, I have an empty desktop and I can't even do a simple ls command in an terminal.

Answer (score 2):

OK this patch

```
patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
vmware3.2.0.patch
```

Works perfectly the only problem was I accidentally hit the update vmware button which screwed everything up at the worst time. I tried everything also trying to uninstall vmware completely. Nothing worked till I was trying to pull the hair out of my bald head.

Then I shutdown the computer and started Ubuntu in an earlier version form the boot loader. I then reinstalled vmware then re install the patch it took!  Finally I then restarted as regular Ubuntu 3.2 and it worked.

Even through you uninstall vmware there's something left in the 3.2 kernel or something

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this workaround

http://communities.vmware.com/message/2005419

They claim to have sorted the problem of installation.

Comment: No, tried his patch, just says I have the wrong version, but I have installed the correct version. I posted above errors.. Thanks

Answer (score -6):

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS in VMware Workstation 8.0.2 without any issues...

Cheers!!

http://mytricks.in/2012/05/guide-how-to-install-ubuntu-12-04-lts-in-vmware-workstation-8.html

Comment: He is referring to the opposite, install VMWare Workstation inside Ubuntu, not Ubuntu inside VMWare.