# How to install VMware 8.0 (not 8.0.2) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, vmware

I installed Vmware 8.0 in ubuntu 12.04, after installation process when i click on vmware icon nothing happens! even don't display any kind of error, what am i supposed to do? does 12.04 support Vmware 8.0?
I found a patch can solve this problem for Vmware 8.0.2 but didn't work for Vmware 8.0.

Comment: After installing VMware 8.0, open a Terminal window (`Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`), type `vmware`, and press enter. That should at least tell you what is going on when you try to run VMware. Then select all the text in the Terminal (`Edit`>`Select All`), copy it to the clipboard (`Edit`>`Copy`), and edit your question, pasting it in, so we can see it. Before submitting your edit, select the text you pasted in and click the icon in the AskUbuntu editing toolbar to make it a code block (otherwise the formatting will be really messed up and it will be impossible to understand).

Comment: Also, please provide details about the patch that solves the problem for VMware 8.0.2 (including, but not limited to, any relevant links), and any other Internet sources you've found about this problem (you found a patch for it for VMware 8.0.2 so I'm guessing you know something about it). And if possible, please explain why you can't just use VMware 8.0.2 (that may help us to understand what your needs are and provide an appropriate workaround for this problem). After all, a license for VMware 8.0 is a license for VMware 8.0.2 also. Finally, what VMware product are you using? (Workstation?)

Comment: surprisingly, when i type `vmware` on terminal nothing appears on the terminal.

Comment: Patch URL [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116565/unable-to-install-vmware-workstation-v8)

Comment: This patch only works for vmware 8.0.2 and i've slow network connection and can't download vmware 8.0.2!

Comment: There are a lot of different ways for "nothing" to happen. When you run `vmware` in the Terminal, does the cursor just stay at the very beginning of the next line, or does it immediately give you a prompt where you could enter another command? Or is there some error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go 8.0.2, I wrote a small tutorial to install VMWARE 8.0.2.

Follow this steps:

Download:

```
https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/downloads
```

Change permissions:

```
chmod +x VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64
```

Run:

```
./VMware-Workstation-Full-8.0.2-591240.x86_64
```

Then run:

```
apt-get install patch
```

After install patch, you must download the VMware correction to your kernel:

```
http://weltall.heliohost.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz
```

Unpack the GZ file:

```
tar -zxvf vmware802fixlinux320.tar.gz
```

Run the Kernel modules patch:

```
./patch-modules_3.2.0.sh
```

Finally, execute VMWARE.

Comment: Thanks but i want to know is there any solutions for installing  vmware 8.0?

Comment: I think there may be patches for other VMware versions. Can you post (or add to your question) a link to the page at heliohost.org that contains the kernel patch link and discusses it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to use the old Workstation version from 2011.
Go to [1](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=WKST-803-LX&productId=241&rPId=2533) and download the appropiate version.
Then apply the patch you found, by changing the line with "8.0.2" to "8.0.3".
After the patch you can use VMware workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the patch at lines 7&8:

> vmreqver=8.0.3
>
> plreqver=4.0.3

To:

> vmreqver=8.0.0
>
> plreqver=4.0.0